# Having issue renaming tags with ActsAsTaggableOn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

Here's my method:

```
def rename
  old_tag = params[:old_tag]
  new_tag = params[:new_tag]

  if old_tag != new_tag
    # find any articles that use the old tag
    Article.tagged_with(old_tag).each do |article|
      # give articles with the old tag the new tag
      article.tag_list.add(new_tag)
      # remove the old tag
      article.tag_list.remove(old_tag)
      article.save
    end
  end

  render :json => "#{old_tag} renamed to #{new_tag}"
end
```

The problem I have is that `.save` is adding a new tag to the articles but it isn't removing the old tag.

Comment: ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true , shouldn't be in the controller.

Comment: Is that old tag being used on another article?

Comment: @andrew I couldn't find where to set remove_unused_tags in the docs so I put it there, I guess has to be in an initialiser. i'm trying to iterate through all the articles that use the old_tag and removing them.@shane

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was facing is that updating tags will initiate validation for all the related models, and in my case the validation was failing due to images not being available on my development machine and attachment validation was failing.

To ignore validation I do:

```
article.save(:validate => false)
```